# How do I redirect a success login from Axios to another page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-functional-component

I want to login success then go to another page. I looked up and search the document, use redux or class component.(I don't use redux.) So I tryed it, Not response.

```
function SignUp(){
  const [redirect, setRedirect]=useState(null);
  if(redirect){
    return <Redirect to={Home}/>
  }
}

export function SignIn({url, id, password}){
    const data={
      id,
      password,
    };
    const params=new URLSearchParams();
    axios(
      {
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        baseURL: ' ',
        data: data,
        params: {
          'id':data.id,
          'password':data.password,
        },
        headers: {
           //code
        },
      }
    )
    .then(function(response){
      if (response.data.response.result==200) {
        SignUp();
        console.log('success');
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

This is the first code I tried.

```
.then(function(response){
      if (response.data.response.result==200) {
        <Route>
         <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/DeviceManage', component:{Home}}}/>
        </Route>
        console.log('success');
      }
    })
```

But didn't respond. TT Thank you for your help in solving the problem.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looke like it is under Javascript context not JSX. Javascript doesn't know how to interpret JSX directly. I'm guessing you are getting Javascript errors by now. Why not try:

```
axios(
  ...
) .then( () => {
   console.log('success');
   window.location.href = '/DeviceManage';

}).catch( ... );
```